# Getting just number of facebook likes

Tags: php, facebook

I'm curious to use the facebook graph API as I don't like the simple like button with number of likes next to it. However I'm finding their documentation a bit confusing. I want to do this via PHP so I'm assuming I need the PHP SDK, is that right?

I'm looking at this page [Graph API: Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/) however I don't understand how I would call the likes.

I'm not asking for someone to code this for me, just a little help in the right direction to understand how it works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $json = @file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/yourpage");
  $json1 = json_decode($json,true);
  $likes = $json1['likes'];
  echo $likes;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward.  Using the ID or the username of the page, access that 
node via the Graph API:

```
PAGE_ID?fields=likes
```

In PHP would be something like:

```
$token_string = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.$appID.'&client_secret='.$app_secret.'&grant_type=client_credentials');
$likes_response = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID?fields=likes&'.$token_string);
$likes_obj = json_decode($likes_response);
$likes = $likes_obj->likes;
echo 'Likes count for page: ' . $likes;
```